# Как в android синхронизировать переменные?

Tags: java, android, синхронизация, global-variables

К примеру, у меня есть fragment, у него есть нужная мне переменная, которую мне надо изменить из адаптера, как это сделать?

Fragment

```
public class AddElementFragment extends Fragment implements interfacce {
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    public ViewPager viewPager;
    String tag = "";
    Resources resources;
    boolean edit;
    itemList itemList = new itemList("","", new ArrayList<itemQuestion>(), 0);

    List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

    RVQuestionAdapter rvQuestionAdapter;

    public ArrayList<itemAnswer> answerItem = new ArrayList<itemAnswer>();

    boolean onEdit = false;

    public int oldId;

    public AddElementFragment setInstance(String tag, boolean edit) {
        AddElementFragment fragment = new AddElementFragment();
        fragment.tag = tag;
        fragment.edit = edit;
        return fragment;
    }

    public AddElementFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void setOldId(int id) {
        this.oldId = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewPager(int page) {
        this.viewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_element, container, false);

        resources = view.getResources();

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        titles.add(getActivity().getString(R.string.text_List));

        View v2 = null;

        Button addAutoAnswer = null;

        switch (tag) {
            case "orph":
                titles.add(resources.getString(R.string.text_AddOrph));
                v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_orph, null);
                addAutoAnswer = (Button) v2.findViewById(R.id.addAuto);
                break;
            case "arif":
                titles.add(resources.getString(R.string.text_AddArif));
                v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_arif, null);
                addAutoAnswer = (Button) v2.findViewById(R.id.addAuto);

                ImageView info = (ImageView) v2.findViewById(R.id.info);

                info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                        LayoutInflater inflater2 = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
                        View AlretDialogForm = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_info_arif, null);

                        builder.setView(AlretDialogForm);
                        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                        alert.show();
                        alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    }
                });

                break;
        }

        View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_question, null);

        final EditText nameList = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.name_list);
        RecyclerView recyclerViewQuestion = (RecyclerView) v1.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        final EditText question = (EditText) v2.findViewById(R.id.inputQuestion);
        final EditText answer = (EditText) v2.findViewById(R.id.inputAnswer);
        Button addAnswer = (Button) v2.findViewById(R.id.addAnswer);
        RecyclerView recyclerViewAnswer = (RecyclerView) v2.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        Button addQuestion = (Button) v2.findViewById(R.id.add);

        LinearLayoutManager llmQuestion = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
        recyclerViewQuestion.setLayoutManager(llmQuestion);

        rvQuestionAdapter = new RVQuestionAdapter(itemList, view.getContext(), this);
        recyclerViewQuestion.setAdapter(rvQuestionAdapter);

        LinearLayoutManager llmAnswer = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
        recyclerViewAnswer.setLayoutManager(llmAnswer);
        final RVAnswerAdapter rvAnswerAdapter = new RVAnswerAdapter(answerItem, view.getContext());
        recyclerViewAnswer.setAdapter(rvAnswerAdapter);

        addQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (edit) {
                    new SaveAndLoad(view.getContext()).SearchFileInId(itemList.id);

                    if (oldId != 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.itemQuestions.size(); i++) {
                            if (itemList.itemQuestions.get(i).id == oldId) {
                                itemQuestion itemQuestion = itemList.itemQuestions.get(i);
                                itemList.itemQuestions.remove(i);
                                itemList.itemQuestions.add(i, new itemQuestion(question.getText().toString(), rvAnswerAdapter.getItemAnswers(),
                                        itemQuestion.True, itemQuestion.False, oldId));

                                boolean res = new SaveAndLoad(view.getContext()).Save(itemList);

                                if (res) {
                                    edit = true;

                                    question.setText("");
                                    answerItem.clear();
                                    answer.setText("");

                                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

                                    rvQuestionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    rvAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                } else {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), resources.getString(R.string.text_failSave),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toast.show();
                                }

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        final Random random = new Random();
                        int idAnswer = random.nextInt(1000000000);
                        itemList.itemQuestions.add(new itemQuestion(question.getText().toString(), rvAnswerAdapter.getItemAnswers(),0,0,idAnswer));
                        boolean res = new SaveAndLoad(view.getContext()).Save(itemList);

                        if (res) {
                            edit = true;

                            question.setText("");
                            answerItem.clear();
                            answer.setText("");

                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

                            rvQuestionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            rvAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), resources.getString(R.string.text_failSave),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    final Random random = new Random();
                    int idList = random.nextInt(1000000000);
                    int idAnswer = random.nextInt(1000000000);

                    itemList.nameList = nameList.getText().toString();
                    itemList.id = idList;
                    itemList.itemQuestions.add(new itemQuestion(question.getText().toString(), answerItem,0,0,idAnswer));
                    itemList.Tag = tag;

                    boolean res = new SaveAndLoad(view.getContext()).Save(itemList);

                    if (res) {
                        edit = true;

                        question.setText("");
                        answerItem.clear();
                        answer.setText("");

                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

                        rvQuestionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        rvAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), resources.getString(R.string.text_failSave),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        addAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                answerItem.add(new itemAnswer(answer.getText().toString(),false));
                rvAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                answer.setText("");
            }
        });

        if (addAutoAnswer != null) {
            addAutoAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (tag) {
                        case "orph":
                           // AutoWord(question, rvAnswerAdapter, view.getContext());
                            break;
                        case "arif":
                            AutoArif(question, rvAnswerAdapter, view.getContext());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        pages.add(v1);
        pages.add(v2);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext(),pages,titles);

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }

    void AutoWord(EditText question, RVAnswerAdapter rvAnswerAdapter, Context context, TextView info1) {
        boolean res = inspectWord(question, info1);

        if (res) {
            ArrayList<itemAnswer> itemAnswers = new AutoWord(question.getText().toString()).Answers();

            if (itemAnswers.size() != 1) {
                answerItem.clear();
                for (int i=0; i<itemAnswers.size(); i++) {
                    answerItem.add(new itemAnswer(itemAnswers.get(i).answer, itemAnswers.get(i).trueElfalse));
                }
                rvAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, resources.getString(R.string.text_falseSearchOrphFalse), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, resources.getString(R.string.text_editWord), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    void AutoArif(EditText question, RVAnswerAdapter rvAnswerAdapter, Context context) {
        ArrayList<itemAnswer> itemAnswers = new AutoArif(question.getText().toString()).Answers();

        if (itemAnswers.size() == 0) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, resources.getString(R.string.text_falseDecisionExample), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            answerItem.clear();
            for (int i=0; i<itemAnswers.size(); i++) {
                answerItem.add(new itemAnswer(itemAnswers.get(i).answer, itemAnswers.get(i).trueElfalse));
            }
            rvAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    boolean inspectWord(EditText WordET, TextView infoText)
    {
        char[] WordChar = WordET.getText().toString().toCharArray();

        int Result = 0;
        int Result2 = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<WordChar.length; i++) {
            if (WordChar[i] == '['|| WordChar[i]==']'||WordChar[i]=='('||WordChar[i]==')') {
                if (Result2 == 0) {
                    Result2 = i;
                } else if (i <= Result2 + 1) {
                    Result = 0;
                    break;
                }
                Result += 1;
            }
        }

        if (Result == 2) {
            infoText.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            return true;
        } else {
            infoText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
    package ru.landmarkstd.educt.Adapters;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import ru.landmarkstd.educt.Fragments.AddElementFragment;
import ru.landmarkstd.educt.Fragments.interfacce;
import ru.landmarkstd.educt.FunctionalClass.ExpandAndCollapce;
import ru.landmarkstd.educt.FunctionalClass.GetEvaluation;
import ru.landmarkstd.educt.FunctionalClass.SaveAndLoad;
import ru.landmarkstd.educt.R;
import ru.landmarkstd.educt.SaveClass.itemList;
import ru.landmarkstd.educt.SaveClass.questionPager;

public class RVQuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    itemList itemList = null;
    Context context;
    Resources resources;
    AddElementFragment addElementFragment;
    interfacce listener;

    public RVQuestionAdapter(itemList itemList, Context context, interfacce listener) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        //this.addElementFragment = addElementFragment;
        resources = context.getResources();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView textViewQuestion;
        LinearLayout CardDetail;
        ImageView open;
        LinearLayout edit;
        LinearLayout remove;
        TextView TrueAnswer;
        TextView FalseAnswer;
        TextView Result;
        ImageView Refresh;
        View view;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            textViewQuestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
            CardDetail = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardDetail);
            open = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.open);
            edit = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            remove = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            TrueAnswer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTrue);
            FalseAnswer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFalse);
            Result = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
            Refresh = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
            view = itemView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_question_card, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textViewQuestion.setText(itemList.itemQuestions.get(position).question);
        holder.TrueAnswer.setText(resources.getString(R.string.text_TrueAnswer) + itemList.itemQuestions.get(position).True);
        holder.FalseAnswer.setText(resources.getString(R.string.text_FalseAnswer) + itemList.itemQuestions.get(position).False);
        holder.Result.setText(resources.getString(R.string.text_Result) +
                new GetEvaluation(itemList.itemQuestions.get(position), resources).Text());

        holder.open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.CardDetail.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    ExpandAndCollapce.expand(holder.CardDetail, 500);

                    ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 180);
                    rotation.setDuration(500);
                    rotation.start();
                } else {
                    ExpandAndCollapce.collapse(holder.CardDetail, 500);

                    ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0);
                    rotation.setDuration(500);
                    rotation.start();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.setOldId(itemList.itemQuestions.get(position).id);
                listener.setViewPager(1);
            }
        });

        holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemList.itemQuestions.remove(position);
                new SaveAndLoad(context).Save(itemList);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.Refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemList itemListRefresh = new SaveAndLoad(context).refreshStatic(itemList, itemList.itemQuestions.get(position).question);

                if (itemListRefresh != null) {
                    itemList = itemListRefresh;
                    boolean resulr = new SaveAndLoad(context).Save(itemList);
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, resources.getString(R.string.text_FalseRefreshStatic), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (itemList.itemQuestions != null) {
            return itemList.itemQuestions.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface

```
package ru.landmarkstd.educt.Fragments;

public interface interfacce {
    void setOldId(int id);
    void setViewPager(int page);
}
```

Comment: Покажите код адаптера и фрагмета. А вообще если просто то mAdapter.getItem(position).yourVariable

Comment: @KirillStoianov 'mAdapter.getItem(position).yourVariable' - Это внутри адаптера, а как именно получить переменную из фрагмента и адаптера ? Обновил. К примеру я хочу изменить 'CodeError' в fragmnet из adaper'a, как вот сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface MyInterface{
    void setVar(Boolean var);
}

public class MyFragment myFragment extends Fragment implements MyInterface{
    private Boolean var;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    void setVar(Boolean var){
        this.var = var;
    }

    @Override
    public View OnCreateView(){
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    } 

    private class MyAdapter extends Adapter{
        MyInterface listener;

        public MyAdapter(MyInterface listener){
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        private changeVar(){
            listener.setVar(true);
        }
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Выдает эту шнягу java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lru/landmarkstd/educt/SaveClass/itemList;Landroid/content/Context;)V in class Lru/landmarkstd/educt/Adapters/RVQuestionAdapter; or its super classes (declaration of 'ru.landmarkstd.educt.Adapters.RVQuestionAdapter' appears in /data/data/ru.landmarkstd.educt/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex)

Comment: Покажи код фрагмента

Comment: @ИванТуаев обновил

Comment: interfacce это имя интерфейса? если да то он пишется с большой буквы. Какие методы объявлены в интерфейсе?

Comment: Изменил имя интерфейса, в интерфейсе объявлены эти методы     void setOldId(int id);
    void setViewPager(int page);

Comment: Попробуй в конструктор адаптера передать AddElementFragment.this вместо просто this

Comment: Тоже саоме 1111

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43458/discussion-between---and-fasd).

Comment: Пере собрал проект и все заработало, Огромное спасибо @ИналТуаев